# Unity 2D change graphics during animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D platformer. I created my hero un photoshop using layers. Saved to PSB and imported it into Unity. Using the 2DAnimatio module I riged some bones and I'm doing my animations using them. Works like a charm.

Ive got this kind of setup:

[image]

With this I can move the parts with ease and create molt of my animations but there are scenarios where I want to, for instance, expose the back of the model. Like in this slash:

[image]

For those Im forced to use frame by frame animation old style, like this : (notice not only the back appearing, but also the sword arm bends and changes. Please notice this is an example I painted in gimp and mouse, just for demonstration purposes)

[image]

How can I tell unity to change to this new sprites during an slash animation and get back again to the rigged sprite for idle and walking animations?? 
I tried:

- Dropping the sliced sprite into a new animation: This leads to having two heroes (the original rigged sprite + the animation one) plus a very difficult positioning of the new sprite (it cannot be moved)
- Create an empty object in my hero, add the animation there, position it there and then disable it. Then by code I can disable the sprite renderer and enable the animation. A bit glitchy and breaks the animator system

What's the expected way to go for it ???

Comment: What do you mean 'frame by frame old school style'? Some screenshots would go a long way. And explain in more details what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: added some images that illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Essentially all of your sprites renderers are in a tree are like such:

    Character
       Body
          Spine
              Shoulder
                  Neck
                      Head
                  Arm1
                  Arm2
    Ect...

Take the renderer of that particular frame and part and change the sprite. The problem is the weight system within unity and how it will manipulate the new sprite.

Otherwise you'd be better off using Adobe character animator or something similar and just exporting the png files of each frame. Simpler to work on and has the same results.

Comment: so @CardCastleStudio your proposal is to use an external program that generate frame by frame animation from rigs. Export the frames. Manually edit those that need it. Import the sprites to Unity. And forget about unity 2DAnimation. Would that be the workflow ?